# Assigning a class based on a property value in angular2 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I would like to assign a classes on html based on a property in angular2. That is am trying top open a dropdownlist without use of jquery and bootstrap

So i have

```
<li
  class="dropdown mega-menu mega-menu-wide"

  //stuck at adding class of open if propertyval is admin
  >  
 <a #admin class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="toggle(admin)" >Administrative</a>
</li>
```

in my ts i have

```
export class ... {
  propertyval :null


   toggle(val){
    this.propertyval = null;
   }
  }
```

So now i would like to assign class of open to the list if the value of propertyval is admin else it should be null

How do i go about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property binding to add the class dynamically.

```
<li
  class="dropdown mega-menu mega-menu-wide"
  [class.WhateverYouWant]="propertyval === 'admin'"
  //stuck at adding class of open if propertyval is admin
  >  
 <a #admin class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="toggle(admin)" >Administrative</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NgClass` directive:

```
<li [ngClass]="{'class-open': open}">  
  <a #admin class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="open = !open;" >Administrative</a>
</li>
```

`class-open` - is your class that affects dropdown list. `open` is your variable that you set initially to false or true in your component, so no need for `toggle()` method.

Comment: the class should be assigned to li not a tag

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use [ngClass] for adding dynamic styles.

```
<a #admin class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="toggle(admin)"  [ngClass]="{'dynStyle': isAdmin }" >Administrative</a>
```

//style

```
.dynStyle{
  color:green;
}
```

//.ts

```
       toggle(val){
        if(val!='admin') 
        {
            this.propertyval = null;
          return isAdmin=false
           }
         else

    {
    return isAdmin=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter on your class, returning boolean for the state of your property.

```
get propertyHasValue(): boolean {
  return !isNullOrUndefined(this.propertyval);
}
```

Then add an ng-class directive to your element

```
<a [ng-class]="{ 'open': propertyHasValue }"/>
```